# xml format error on return

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

I got `TypeError: Error #1088: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.`

But the output of this string look correct to me.

```
<midifile>C:\Users\XYZ\Desktop\white_night_in_G.mp3</midifile>
<resolution>240</resolution>
<tick>77767</tick>
<ttrack>5</ttrack>
<tpatches>0</tpatches>
<tduration>226.063</tduration>


var xmlResults:XML = new XML(message);
xmlResults.ignoreWhite = true;
```

Answer (score 3):

is that the entire xml markup? you are missing the a root tag. Try

```
<item>
<midifile>C:\Users\XYZ\Desktop\white_night_in_G.mp3</midifile>
<resolution>240</resolution>
<tick>77767</tick>
<ttrack>5</ttrack>
<tpatches>0</tpatches>
<tduration>226.063</tduration>
</item>
```

Comment: I found where my mistake was, related to the return data in Nativeprocess is not complete, therefore, was deem as incomplete XML data.